# Jenkins can't find defined function?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I wrote this to test the idea I saw on [JENKINS-44085](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44085?focusedCommentId=346951&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-346951)

```
def generateStage(String job, String targetVersion,
                  String rootVersion, Integer sleepTime=0) {
    return {
        stage("Deploying: ${job}") {
            sleep sleepTime
            println "Job: $job"
        }
    }
}

def deployProcs(targetVersion, rootVersion) {
    script {
        int sleepTime = 0
        def procs = ["proc-proc", "proc-proc-high"]
        def parallelStagesMap = procs.collectEntries {
            ["${it}" : generateStage(it, targetVersion, rootVersion, sleepTime)]
            sleepTime += 5
        }
        timestamps {
            parallel parallelStagesMap
        }
    }
}

node('linux') {
  deployProcs(10, 10)
}
```

But I get

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'generateStage' found among steps.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `deployProcs(10, 10)` where both parameters are type of `Integer`. The same integer parameters are used when calling `generateStage`, which parameters are typed `String targetVersion` and `String rootVersion`.

A fix is to either, call `deployProcs('10', '10')` or change `def generateStage(String job, Integer targetVersion, Integer rootVersion, Integer sleepTime=0)`, or remove types from `generateStage` function parameters.

Comment: How'd I miss that? I did passed String parms in the function call. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea why does this happen? Why it wont raise an error about datatype mismatch? It is raising NoSuchMethodError.

Comment: @Azee77 Groovy can have multiple methods with same name but different parameter types (method overloading) for methods that have explicit parameter types. Method name and its parameter types form method _signature_ that is used when finding the method to run. See example here: https://onecompiler.com/groovy/3zeg63xaw